# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: " "

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, jxl

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
```

I am getting the above error as I am inputting some empty values from the excel file, I am copying to another excel workbook. For empty fields, I don't want any output.
So, how to go ahead. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
public class excel_read {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException,      RowsExceededException, WriteException
{
    File fExcel = new File("C:\\Users\\Master\\Desktop\\fwdautomationforsmb\\new.xls");

    WritableWorkbook writableBook = Workbook.createWorkbook(fExcel);
    writableBook.createSheet("Data", 0);

    WritableSheet writableSheet = writableBook.getSheet(0);

    Xls_Reader datatable = new Xls_Reader("C:\\Users\\Master\\Desktop\\fwdautomationforsmb\\Workbook1.xlsx");
    int rows_count = datatable.getRowCount("Sheet1");
    System.out.println("Total number of rows = " + rows_count);

    for(int i=2; i<rows_count;i++)
    {
    String date_list = datatable.getCellData("Sheet1", "Past/Nearing Expiration Date",   i);

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date());

    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 30); 
    String output = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());

    String dateInString1 = date_list;
    Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(dateInString1);
    String dateInString2 = output;

    Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(dateInString2);

     if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0){
        // System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
      }

     else if(date1.compareTo(date2)<0){

         System.out.println(date_list);
         Label data1 = new Label(0, i, date_list);
            writableSheet.addCell(data1);
     }

     else if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0){
         System.out.println(date_list);
         Label data1 = new Label(0, i, date_list);
            writableSheet.addCell(data1);
     }

   }

    writableBook.write();
    writableBook.close();

   }
 }
```

Comment: What is the format of date ?

Comment: So check for the empty string first?

Comment: Error you get means that you are trying to parse an empty string. Debug your code to find the problem source.

Comment: "dd/MM/yyyy"
@JonK, How to check that. Sorry I am not very good at java right now

Comment: @Rafael Osipov,  Yes, I have empty fields in the excel file

Comment: @user3690170 check on empty string before parse it to a date object.

Comment: See @JamesB's answer for a potential way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for empty string before calling the parse method:

```
if(dateInString1 != null && !dateInString1.isEmpty()) {
    Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(dateInString1);
}
```

If you are sure that the field will not be null, you can leave out the null check.

Comment: You could also drop it down to a single comparison by doing `!"".equals(dateInString1)`, as that will return false if dateInString1 is null. Either way is fine.

Comment: @JonK I prefer isEmpty() myself.

Comment: As I said, either way is fine. I prefer the Yoda condition because it's shorter and null-safe. Doubt it makes any real difference one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

1. What are doing by this?

   `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   c.setTime(new Date());
   c.add(Calendar.DATE, 30); 
   String output = dateFormat.format(c.getTime());
   String dateInString2 = output;
   Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(dateInString2);`

   Don't you think date2==c.getTime(); ????
2. And regarding the ParseException - you can just surround parse block in try/catch block and catch ParseException instead of throwing it. (To be more clear remove ParseException for main method and surround line with dateFormat.parse() with try catch.